# Vectors in 3D 3 Body Problem, Error that vector needs x, y, dy, and dx

Tags: python, vector, physics, vpython

I used the skeleton of a code modeling the three body problem. However, I am trying to figure out why the vectors will not work. I have commented them out (lines 56-60) so that I can see the rest of the program working. I'll attach the code so you can see the error. It is an error telling me the specs for a vector, but I don't see why the input wouldn't work. Thanks !

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from vpython import * 
from IPython.display import display


scene = display(title = "Earth's Orbit", width = 500, height = 500, range = 3.e11)

# #
# scene.autoscale = 0       # Turn off auto scaling of display
#

# Define the Sun and the Earth objects.

#
sun = sphere(color = color.yellow)
earth = sphere(color = color.blue)
venus = sphere(color = color.red)

# Gravitational constant (Nm**2/kg**2)
G = 6.67 * 10 ** -11
sun.pos = vector(0, 0, 0)       # Initial Sun position (m)
earth.pos = vector(0, -149.6 * 10 ** 7, 149.6 * 10 ** 9)        # Initial Earth position (m)
venus.pos = vector(1.0820948 * 10 **11, -1.0820948 * 10 **11, 0)    # Initial Venus position (m)

rhat = -norm(earth.pos)     # Getting Magnitude, probably going touse normalized vectors for simplicity
sun.mass = 2 * 10 ** 30         # Mass of the Sun (kg)
earth.mass = 6 * 10 ** 24   # Mass of the Earth (kg)
venus.mass = 4.867 * 10 ** 24   # Mass of Venus (kg)
earth.velocity = vector(30 * 10 ** 3, 0, 0)
venus.velocity = vector(35.02 * 10 ** 3, 0, 0)

# Initial velocity in seconds (THIS IS WHERE WE CAN CHANGE THINGS UP BUT BE SENSIBLE)
dt = 86000
#
total = 0               #Initializes the totl elpsed time
#
# Scale factors to control how big the Earth and Sun are drawn in the display
#
sun.scale = 1e1
earth.scale = 5e2
venus.scale = earth.scale
#
sun.radius = 7.e8 * sun.scale
earth.radius = 6.4e6 * earth.scale
venus.radius = 6.052e6 * venus.scale
#
#Initialize the momentum and path of the Earth
#
earth.momentum = earth.mass * earth.velocity    # momentum of Earth
venus.momentum = venus.mass * venus.velocity    # momentum of Venus
earth.trail = curve(color = earth.color)        # Defines Earth's path
# Set initial position of the Earth 
earth.trail.append(pos = earth.pos)
#
# Define an arrow thata points from the origin to the Earth
#
##rearrow = arrow(pos = (0, 0, 0) ,axis = earth.pos,
##              color = earth.color, shaftwidth = 1e6)
##momentumArrow = arrow(pos = earth.pos, axis = earth.momentum, 
##              color = earth.color, shaftwidth = 1e6)

#
tmax = 3600 * 24 * 364.25       # Number of seconds in a year 
#
# Start of the loop structure
#
while(True):
    #
    rate(100)       # limit the loop to a maximum of 100 times per second
#
# Fill in the next 3 lines with the correct expressions

    earthToSun = -norm(earth.pos)
    venusToSun = -norm(venus.pos)
    earthToVenus = -norm(earth.pos - venus.pos)
    # Compute the force that the Sun exerts on the Earth and added Venus's influence
    earth.force = ((G * earth.mass * sun.mass) / (mag(earth.pos)) ** 2 * rhat
    + G * venus.mass * earth.mass / mag(earth.pos - venus.pos) ** 2 * earthToVenus)
    earth.momentum = earth.momentum + earth.force * \
    dt      # Update Earth's momentum

    # Let's updaate Earth's position
    earth.pos = earth.pos + (earth.momentum / earth.mass) * dt

    forceEarth = (G * earth.mass * venus.mass) / (mag(earth.pos - venus.pos)) ** 2 * earthToVenus
    forceSun = G * venus.mass * sun.mass / (mag(venus.pos)) ** 2 * venusToSun
    venus.force = forceEarth + forceSun
    venus.momentum += venus.force * dt

    venus.pos += (venus.momentum / venus.mass) * dt

momentumArrow.pos = earth.pos
momentumArrow.axis = earth.momentum * 10 ** -18
earth.trail.append(pos = earth.pos)     # Updates Earth' trail
rearrow.axis = earth.pos                # Move Earth's position arrow

total = total + dt                  #Increment the Time
#
# Print
#
print(earth.pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

(0,0,0) is not a vector, it's a Python tuple. You need to say vector(0,0,0) or vec(0,0,0).